# JS canvas resizing in all sides

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to resize a canvas in all directions [the way Photoshop does](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/photoshop-understand-canvas-size.html).

I tried with JS but it's not matching the output I got from the Photoshop CC canvas size feature.

Original Image (600 x 439): https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IHvs.jpg

Resized with JS code (580 x 430): https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDaWl.png

Resized with Photoshop CC (Image->Canvas Size) (580 x 430): https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTCCp.jpg

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var width = 580;
var height = 430;

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height);
};
imageObj.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IHvs.jpg';
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="580" height="430"></canvas>
</body>
```

So, any idea how I can resize canvas in all directions the way photoshop CC does so that it can match to output of Photoshop CC.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f2L4b942/

Comment: you mean, resize a canvas according to the image size?

Comment: That's the difference between linear interpolation and cubic interpolation. You can't do much about it unless you write your own image renderer.

Comment: @siam  ya , you can check output images i attached in Question , open them in new tab and then switch between tabs you will noticed the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is just to crop your image, but keep the anchor point in the middle.

This is easily implemented :
Set the `x` and `y` parameters of `drawImage` to the difference between the required size and the original one, divided by 2.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var requiredWidth = canvas.width = 580;
var requiredHeight = canvas.height = 430;
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
  // all you need is here
  var offsetX = (requiredWidth - img.naturalWidth) / 2;
  var offsetY = (requiredHeight - img.naturalHeight) / 2;
  
  context.drawImage(img, offsetX, offsetY, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
};
img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/rXURSWC.jpg';
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="580" height="430"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by redefining the canvas `width` and `height` upon image load ...

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = this.width;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y);
};
imageObj.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/rXURSWC.jpg';
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#myCanvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="580" height="430"></canvas>
```

Comment: its not changing size of canvas even ?  https://jsfiddle.net/f2L4b942/2/
i downloaded image from it and its 600 x 439

Comment: @user889030 its not clear. do you wanna resize the image to `580 x 430` or resize the canvas to `600 x 439` ?

Comment: actual image size is :: 600 x 439
and i was resizing it to 580 x 430

Comment: it render original image and change size back to 600 x 439  although you setup  canvas size 580 x 430